# How do I implement authentication for Azure Mobile App in Xamarin.Forms using Apple signin

Tags: azure, xamarin, mobile

My app submission to the Apple Store got rejected because it requires users to log in though it does not implement Apple sign-in. My app is written in Xamarin.Form and uses Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client to communicate with my Azure Mobile App backend. It supports authentication with Facebook, Google, Twitter and Microsoft. For all those providers I use the "server flow". I followed some instructions I found on Apple sign-in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/signinwithapple/

I got to the point where I get a userId and a token from the client but I am stuck on what to do next to enable authentication with the Azure Mobile App service.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!